# iOS 7 UISearchBar right spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

Don't know why, my search bar in iOS 7 is leaving a right space. It's ok in iOS 6.

I know it has something to do with the section index, because if I remove it the space disappears, but I don't know how to fix it. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: is your Searchbar subview of first tableviewcell?

Comment: No, is a subview of the UITableView

Comment: please show me the code that you add searchbar as subview of tableview!

Comment: I just do it in storyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until a better answer appears, I just manually changed the frame of the search bar like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];        

    CGRect barFrame = self.searchBar.frame;
    barFrame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    self.searchBar.frame = barFrame;

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem like question is. Your code help, but its a little thing.. Than i scroll (in calls viewDidLayoutSubviews method) searchbar width = 320 and textfile in it ~ 300. But if i tap in textfiled and it will focused in and click cancel - searcbar width become 320 and textfiled in it will be about 290. To resolve it we should 1 more time change frame of SearchBr manualy

Comment: AMAZING!!
I'm surprised about this iOS7 stupid bug, thanks for you awesome answer. 
I think that in iOS7 indexes into table views are awful.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with a UISearchDisplayController

Answer (score 7):

Embed your UISearchBar in a UIView and then add that as the tableHeaderView.  Structuring it that way in a storyboard worked for me.  I'm guessing iOS resizes the UISearchBar in the tableHeaderView, but leaves a basic UIView alone (and doesn't bother to look inside it).

You might also want to make the section index transparent, which I did with:

```
[[UITableView appearance] setSectionIndexBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[UITableView appearance] setSectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue with the iPhone 6/ 6Plus when using a SearchDisplayController. (Using Swift)

I tried setting the frame of the search bar but with no luck but i noticed that if i tapped on the textField of the UISearchBar and then cancelled it then it would take on the proper size of the view. I therefore managed to fix the issue by calling the code below in ViewDidLoad of the viewController using the search.

```
self.searchController.setActive(true, animated: false)
self.searchController.setActive(false, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
self.contactsTableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The reason for that white edge is because your index layer has a white background and is on top of the search bar. This should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Add the search bar inside a UIView put as tableView's header view.  Set the tableview's `sectionIndexBackgroundColor` to clear color because it covers the header.

Tested with iOS 7, 7.1;

Answer (score 1):

Because the table view always leaves 15px on the right for section Indexes View, so you should resize the Seach bar after reloading the table view

**First:**

```
self.tblData.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //(iOS >= 7 only)
```

**Cheating time:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

    [self performSelector:@selector(resizeSearchBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
- (void) resizeSearchBar
{
    CGRect frame = self.searchBar.frame;
    if (frame.size.width < self.tblData.frame.size.width) {
        frame.size.width = self.tblData.frame.size.width;
    }
    self.searchBar.frame = frame;
}
- (void) reloadTableData // call it anytime you want to reload table view
{
    [self.tblData reloadData];
    [self performSelector:@selector(resizeSearchBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
```

**Suggest**
Dont cheat like me, just do the simpler way:

```
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal; // iOS >= 7 only
```

Comment: I don't think you need to resize the search bar every time the table view scrolls.

Comment: eachtime table view scrolling, it will change your search bar size.

Comment: It doesn't in my case.

Comment: did you try to reload the table by using my code ?
[self reloadTableData];

Answer (score 0):

I also attached a `UISearcBar` in my application, and nothing is wrong there even my application supports rotation also.

Could you try removing and re creating `UISearchBar` in `storyboard/xib`

Comment: Same thing happens. Do you have the section index to the right of the table view as I do?

Comment: No i dont. Try setting `SearchBar` `width constraints` in `autolayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I added the search bar as a subview of the top-level view instead of the table view. Used autolayout to pin the searchbar to the top guide, and a vertical space constraint of 0 between the search bar and the table view.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution with the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews` makes the screen flicker.
Instead what I did was create a subclass of `UISearchBar` that simply does this:

FullWidthSearchBar.h:

```
@interface FullWidthSearchBar : UISearchBar
@end
```

FullWidthSearchBar.m:

```
#import "FullWidthSearchBar.h"
@implementation FullWidthSearchBar

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.size.width = self.superview.bounds.size.width;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

And then I assigned that class to the search bar on my xib:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the right white block, so if we change the block color the same as the search bar background, it looks normal.

just

```
if (IOS7) {
    self.tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.searchBar.backgroundImage];
}
```